# Face API Python SDK "Image Size too Small" (PersonGroupPerson add_face_from_stream)

Tags: python, azure, azure-cognitive-services, face-recognition, face-api

First things first, the documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure-cognitiveservices-vision-face/azure.cognitiveservices.vision.face.operations.persongrouppersonoperations?view=azure-python) says "JPEG, PNG, GIF (the first frame), and BMP format are supported. The allowed image file size is from 1KB to 6MB."

I am sending a .jpg that is ~1.4 MB
In my search, others who had this issue were custom forming packets and ran into issues chunk transfering images.
however unlike the [others](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51433688/invalidimagesize-message-image-size-is-too-small) I am not forming my own API call, just passing a jpg to the python sdk.
What is going wrong/what am I missing?

The error is:

```
getting image, start time
opening image:  2019_11_30_18_40_21.jpg
time elapsed for capturing image: 8.007975816726685
time elapsed for detecting image: 0.0017137527465820312
appending face found in image
identifying face
time elapsed for identifying image: 0.8008027076721191
Person for face ID e7b2c3fe-6a62-471f-8371-8c1e96608362 is identified in 2019_11_30_18_40_21.jpg with a confidence of 0.68515.
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "./GreeterCam_V0.1 - testing.py", line 116, in <module>
face_client.person_group_person.add_face_from_stream(PERSON_GROUP_ID, face.candidates[0].person_id, image)
File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/azure/cognitiveservices/vision/face/operations/_person_group_person_operations.py", line 785, in add_face_from_stream
raise models.APIErrorException(self._deserialize, response)
azure.cognitiveservices.vision.face.models._models_py3.APIErrorException: (InvalidImageSize) Image size is too small.
```

my source code is:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    FRAMES_PER_SECOND = 0.13
    ENDPOINT = os.environ['COGNITIVE_SERVICE_ENDPOINT']
    KEY = os.environ['COGNITIVE_SERVICE_KEY']
    face_client = FaceClient(ENDPOINT, CognitiveServicesCredentials(KEY))
    PERSON_GROUP_ID = 'my-unique-person-group'
    #IMAGES_FOLDER = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__)))
    #camera = PiCamera()
    #camera.start_preview()
    test_images = [file for file in glob.glob('*.jpg')]
    #webcam = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
    while(True):
        start_time = time.time()
        print('getting image, start time')
        for image_name in test_images:
            image = open(image_name, 'r+b')
            print("opening image: ", image_name)
            time.sleep(5)
            faces = face_client.face.detect_with_stream(image)     
            #image = open(os.path.join(IMAGES_FOLDER, imageName), 'r+b')
            face_ids = []
            time1 = time.time()
            print('time elapsed for capturing image: ' + str(time1-start_time))
            # detect faces in image

            time2 = time.time()
            print('time elapsed for detecting image: ' + str(time2-time1))
            for face in faces:
                print('appending face found in image')
                face_ids.append(face.face_id)
            if face_ids:
                print('identifying face')
                # if there are faces, identify person matching face
                results = face_client.face.identify(face_ids, PERSON_GROUP_ID)
                time3 = time.time()
                print('time elapsed for identifying image: ' + str(time3-time2))
                name = 'person-created-' + str(time.strftime("%Y_%m_%d_%H_%M_%S"))
                if not results:
                    #if there are no matching persons, make a new person and add face
                    print('No person in the person group for faces from {}.'.format(imageName))
                    new_person = face_client.person_group_person.create(PERSON_GROUP_ID, name)
                    face_client.person_group_person.add_face_from_stream(PERSON_GROUP_ID, new_person.person_id, image)
                    time4 = time.time()
                    print('time elapsed for creating new person: ' + str(time4-time3))
                    print('New Person Created: {}'.format(new_person.person_id))
                for face in results:
                    if not face.candidates:
                        new_person = face_client.person_group_person.create(PERSON_GROUP_ID, name)
                        face_client.person_group_person.add_face_from_stream(PERSON_GROUP_ID, new_person.person_id, image)
                    else:
                        #add face to person if match was found
                        print('Person for face ID {} is identified in {} with a confidence of {}.'.format(face.face_id, os.path.basename(image.name), face.candidates[0].confidence)) # Get topmost confidence score
                        face_client.person_group_person.add_face_from_stream(PERSON_GROUP_ID, face.candidates[0].person_id, image)
                        time4 = time.time()
                        print('time elapsed for creating new person: ' + str(time4-time3))
```

Also this is on Raspbian on a pi 3B(+?)

Comment: maybe it is too small in `WIDTH x HEIGHT`, not in `MB`.

Comment: @furas maybe theoretically, but I doubt this is the issue here since I am using a normal sized image with a normal aspect ratio

Comment: it is possible. In other question with recognizing in PyTesseract solution was to resize image 120%. But I would display filename to check image which makes problem. Maybe accidently this file is different then other.

Comment: @davidt is this code sample complete? I just worked with another user getting the "image too small error" and it turns out the steps in creating a person group were incomplete. I am trying your sample and I don't see that you created a person group. Or maybe that person group already exists? I wanted to address this, as the code implemented in the right order would not need the file I/O statement as a parameter, as I see the workaround as the answer has shown. I also have working samples of the Identify API call, if that is what you were after.

Comment: @Azurespot Yes I had aleady created a person group, and the accepted solution fixed my problem. Are you saying that I should not have to provide an image from file at all when using the person_group_person.add_face_from_stream(...) function? Or is there a better way to handle the creation of a new person if the face.identify(...) fails? I would like to see your working samples.

Comment: @davidt, I modified your sample a bit to separate the API calls out for clarity. In this example, you'll see that no modifications are necessary for the `add_face_from_stream` function. I found that in your sample, it was a scope issue that was causing that error. I hope this helps. I don't have a place to upload my images right now, but I will try to do that soon if you wanted to download and test. https://github.com/Azure-Samples/cognitive-services-quickstart-code/blob/master/python/Face/DetectIdentifyFace,py

Comment: @davidt here are the images. https://github.com/Azure-Samples/cognitive-services-sample-data-files/tree/master/Face/images

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I run your code on my side and got the same error .Seems there is something wrong with `image` param in code :

```
face_client.person_group_person.add_face_from_stream(PERSON_GROUP_ID, face.candidates[0].person_id, image)
```

at the phase:

> #add face to person if match was found

When I changed this line code to :

```
face_client.person_group_person.add_face_from_stream(PERSON_GROUP_ID, face.candidates[0].person_id, open(image_name,"r+b"))
```

The issue was solved, faces has been added to a person successfully (this person has 1 face before)  :

[image: ![enter image description here]

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you for your help! I will try this fix this evening.

Comment: Hi @davidt , how's going? Has your issue been solved?

Comment: Solved! very odd that the image opening has to be in the argument. I would think my code would be equivalent. Thank you for your help!!!!!!

Comment: This worked because the image variable was lost in scope, that's why opening it inside the parameter eliminated the scope issue. But the downside is that image is not available anywhere else now. I added a sample link in the comments of the question for an alternative code layout that keeps the image both in scope and available as a variable for other processes.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this as well. This is because the stream has already been read when you use it in the `detect_with_stream`

You can go `image.seek(0)` or close the image and reopen it - but seeking is the better solution.

Comment: Don't post another question in an answer. Post it as a comment to the question or post another question

Comment: I didn't ask any questions.

Comment: Before you edit your post, I see a question statement. But no problem it's in acceptable form now.

Comment: Not everything with a question mark is really a question - but thanks for fastidiously policing the replies I guess

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the same error because I was openning the photo before the recognition. So I removed the open and the code worked.